# Simple Date Format parsing PM time incorrectly as AM time

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm working with the following snippet which takes a datetime as a string, then creates a `Date` object from it:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d 'at' h:mm a");

currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2014-03-06 12:59:01");
System.out.println(f.format(currentDate));
```

The last two lines give an output of "Thursday, March 6 at 12:59 **AM**", but it should be **PM**.  What is causing this?  It only happens for the noontime am/pm switch.  For example if the time being parsed was `("2014-03-06 00:59:01")` the output is correctly "Thursday, March 6 at 12:59 **AM**".  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2014-03-06 12:59:01");
```

contains `hh` which is the 1-12 hour format.  Try using capital `HH`, which uses 0-23 format.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Output:

```
Thursday, March 6 at 12:59 PM
```

The date formatting symbols and descriptions are in [the `SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).